# Selecting a Graphic Element on button click using IGraphicContainerSelect

Tags: c#, casting, element, containers, arcobjects

I am having trouble type casting and using the right interfaces. I have a function that loops through all text elements with a specific property set. Once a match is found, I want to be able to select this text element or make it active or highlighted or whatever on the map. Code below.

```
protected override void OnClick(Item item)
{
IMxDocument pDoc = ValidateInterface.GetMxDocument();
IActiveView pLayout = (IActiveView)pDoc.PageLayout;
IGraphicsContainer pGraphicsCont = (IGraphicsContainer)pDoc.PageLayout;
pGraphicsCont.Reset();

        IElementProperties _ElemProps = null;
        while ((_ElemProps = (IElementProperties)pGraphicsCont.Next()) != null)
        {
            if (_ElemProps.CustomProperty is IPropertySet2)
            {
                ITextElement _textElement = (ITextElement)_ElemProps;
                IPropertySet2 _propertySet = (IPropertySet2)_ElemProps.CustomProperty;
                MessageBox.Show("Before I compare item to string");
                if (item.Caption == Convert.ToString(_propertySet.GetProperty(NAME_STRING)))
                {
                    //Problems start here
                    MessageBox.Show("Inside the IF statement");
                    IGraphicsContainerSelect _SelectMyElement = null;   // = (IGraphicsContainerSelect)pGraphicsCont;
                    ITextElement _newTextElement = (ITextElement)pGraphicsCont;
                    IElement TestElement = _newTextElement as IElement;

                    _SelectMyElement.SelectElement(TestElement);
                }
            }
        }
```

}

Nothing is being selected though on my map. I'm looping through each graphic element (IGraphicContainer) on the map. Once I find a match, I want to select that Graphic Element. I am trying to utilize IGraphicContainerSelect to do this. It takes an IElement variable type as a parameter, thus why I'm trying to cast it. But again, noting is being selected. This all happens when I click a button.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your map. 
I think the better way using pLayout.PartialRefresh or pScreenDisplay.Invalidate methods.

```
pLayout.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphicSelection,null,pLayout.Extent)
```

OR

```
IScreenDisplay pScreenDisplay = pLayout.ScreenDisplay;
pScreenDisplay.Invalidate(null,false,esriViewGraphicSelection);
pScreenDisplay.UpdateWindow();
```

See help :http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000242000000